# How to load register with predefined bytes in Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

Using ARM assembly, I want to load R0 with predefined bytes A, B, C, D. In the `.data` section I have them defined as:

```
A:    .byte    0xFF
B:    .byte    0xAA
C:    .byte    0x88
D:    .byte    0x77
```

I want R0 to be `FFAA8877` when all is said and done. Not sure I should be using `.byte` or `.word` or even something else for A, B, C, D.

EDIT:
Here is what I'm trying to do with R0:

```
@on entry: R0 holds the word to be swapped
@on exit: R0 holds the swapped word, R1 is destroyed
@R0 = A, B, C, D
byteswap:
    EOR R1, R0, R0, ROR #16
    BIC R1, R1, #0xFF0000
    MOV R0, R0, ROR #8
    EOR R0, R0, R1, LSR #8
```

Comment: If you really need to have them in the datasection for some reason, just define it as MyValue: .word 0xFFAA8877 and later in the code use ldr r0, =MyValue and ldr r0, [r0] The first will load the address the second will load from that address.

Comment: The reason why I need A, B, C, D is to byteswap R0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shortcut.

```
ldr r0,=0xFFAA8877
```

Or you can do the same thing manually...

```
ldr r0,my_number
...
my_number: .word 0xFFAA8877
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running little-endian ARM, here is how you can do it:

```
ldr r0, =A
ldr r1, [r0]
rev r0, r1
```

Note that the [rev instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihjgdid.html) does the conversion from little-endian to big-endian. Note that the rev instruction is available only armv6+.

If you are running big-endan ARM, just skip the rev instruction and you'll be fine :)

Edit: rev instruction was incorrect.

Comment: The purpose of this is to swap the bytes of R0 between little-endian and big-endian. I'll add the instructions to the OP